Non-Regular DCFL Without Prefix Property

A language $ L $ has the prefix property if there are no two distinct strings $ x $ and $ y $ in $ L $ such that $ x $ is a prefix of $ y $.


It is known that a language $ L $ is accepted by a Deterministic Pushdown Automaton (DPDA) by emptying its stack if and only if:

$ L $ has the prefix property, and
$ L $ is accepted by some DPDA by reaching a final state.


I am looking for an example of a non-regular language that is:

Accepted by a DPDA by final state, but
Not accepted by a DPDA by emptying its stack (i.e., does not have the prefix property).

If we relax the non-regularity condition, $ 0^* $ serves as an example. This language is a DCFL (since all regular languages are DCFL) and does not have the prefix property because strings like $ 0 $ and $ 00 $ are both in the language, and $ 0 $ is a proper prefix of $ 00 $.
However, I specifically need a non-regular DCFL satisfying the above conditions.

Edit.
I think I found an example. Does $\{ba^nb^n\mid n\geq 0\}$ work?

Yes your example works, as you yourself explain, $b$ is a prefix of all $ba^nb^n$.
It seems that the idea in your example can be generalized. Take any (nonregular) DCFL $L$ with the prefix property. Let $a$ be the first letter of a word in $L$, assuming $a\notin L$. Now $L \cup\{a\}$ is again a (nonregular) DCFL but no longer has the prefix property.
Another solution is $\{a^nb^m \mid m\ge n\}$.
Also $\{w\in \{a,b\}^* \mid \#_a(w) = \#_b(w) \}$ is a candidate.

But $b$ is a prefix of $bab$ as an example. Am I wrong?

Oops. You are right. Forgot about the $n=0$ case.

There's a typo in the first line - $ba^na^n$ should say $ba^nb^n$. It's too small for a suggested edit.

@user2357112 Thanks.
